# Parse file to DataTable

Tags: c#, excel, dbf

I have to parse file with `.xls` extention into `DataTable` object. Seems like file is text table with fixed columns length in `cp866` encoding, but I couldn't read it with appropriate connection string.

I can successfully open such files with `MS Excel`, and it writting *Opening DBF 4* while it opening. Below example of reading attempt such file as simple text, and you may notice that some characters are not recognized.

Can somebody help to solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that it's corrupt `dbf4` file. You could try to read it using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` package:

```
Application app = new Application { Visible = false };
Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(fileFullName, UpdateLinks: 0, ReadOnly: true, CorruptLoad: 1);
Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets.Item[1];
Range r = ws.UsedRange;

object[,] va = (object[,])r.Value2;
int rowLen = va.GetLength(0);
int colLen = va.GetLength(1);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 1; i <= rowLen; i++)
{
    object[] row = new object[colLen];

    for (int j = 1; j <= colLen; j++)
    {
        row[j - 1] = va[i, j];
    }

    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(";", row));
}

string result = sb.ToString();

wb.Close(false, fileFullName, null);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wb);
app.Quit();
```